# Restrict drag/drop for a node in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

can somebody please tell how to use this solution to solve my problem. I too want to restrict drag/drop for a node whose id has text "not" in it.

[jsTree drag and drop restrict folders by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374452/jstree-drag-and-drop-restrict-folders-by-class)

here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/112/

```
"crrm" : {
    "move" : {
        "default_position" : "first",
        "check_move" : function (m) {  
            return (m.o.hasClass("locked") || m.r.hasClass("locked")) ? false : true;  
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I already given that but not able to implement

Comment: @ejay I already try to implement But not able to do can you change my fiddle

Comment: just replace `m.o.hasClass("locked") || m.r.hasClass("locked")` with `m.o.attr('id').indexOf('not') !== -1 || m.r.attr('id').indexOf('not') !== -1`

Comment: wait I will update you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/114/ check this not working ..:(

Comment: @Ejay any idea how to remove this error

Comment: are you sure your `crrm` plugin is included AND working?

Comment: From where I got Crrm plugin ..can you please check fiddle and check external source.I don't use that

Comment: Where you please give link of crrm plugin so that I download and include that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I looked into it and I think it is working. It seems that `crrm` plugin is no more available for `jstree` AND you can achieve your result using only `dnd` plugin using following self-explanatory code

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
       check_callback: function (op, node, node_parent) {
          return op == 'move_node' ? node_parent.id.indexOf('not') === -1 : true;
       }
    },
    dnd: {
       is_draggable: function (x) {
          return x[0].id.indexOf('not') === -1;
       }
    },
    "plugins": ["dnd"]
 });
```

This code prevents moving of said nodes and also prevents moving of other nodes into them.

Comment: Thanks for replay ..can it is possible that "not" type move or add  those element which don't have child.They can be add on "a" , "b-b-a"..etc

Comment: what are you **actually** trying to achieve? Answer to your original question is right there

Comment: yes sir this is perfect answer I am thankful to you ..I need that those element whose id having  character "not" can only add those node  which don't have child..

Comment: It mean "c-a","b-b" both element  add only "a" ,"b-a","b-b-a","b-b-b" Not to "b" "b-b"

Comment: both  "c-a" and "b-b" can they can become child of individual

Comment: are you lookinh for issue

Comment: It is confusing. You want to move `c-a` and `b-b` to empty nodes or move empty nodes into `c-a` and `b-b`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52694/discussion-between-naveen-sharma-and-ejay)

Comment: sure. Can you just call me Ejay? You saying 'sir' makes me feel you're talking to my father :D

Comment: please do it I am waiting for that